# so an adjective/ adverb that

Tags: adverbs, adjectives, conjunctions, intensifiers

... the period was so far like the present period that some of...

**She was so much beautiful that...**

She was so beautiful that...

As far as I know the bold one is incorrect because we mustn't add another intensifier after so.

I am wondering the reason why, although there has been used another intensifier" far", the sentence is correct, isn't it?

Please feel free to ask any further question if my question in not vivd enough.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: where is *italic one!*

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is not grammatical.  At first I thought that "so far " meant "up to {this/that} point"

- The period was, so far, like the present period...

But then one runs into the "that"!  So then one has to re-parse thus:

- X was so far like Y that ...{clause}

This does not make sense. "so far like" is not idiomatic. (things can be "far apart" or "far away" but not "far like").  You would say "so much like":
- X is like Y
- X is much like Y 
- X is so much like Y that {clause}

So unless the context somehow untangles this problem (and I really would like to see the full sentence, and maybe the one that preceds it), I would have to say your first example is not a correct usage.

Answer (score 0):

"So far" is an idiom meaning;
1. Up to the present moment: So far there's been no word from them.
2. To a limited extent: You can go only so far on five dollars.

In the first sentence you mentioned, the second meaning could have been intended;
... the period was *to a limited extent* like the present period that some of...

You are correct about using "so" as an adverb to modify adjectives, it should be just before the adjective;
She was so happy that she cried. 
She was so beautiful that...

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

When a word can not be classified as a noun/pronoun/adjective/verb/preposition/conjunction etc, it's classified as an adverb. So calling a word an adverb is not that helpful. Because an adverb in a sentence is used in various ways, and not all adverbs can be used the same way.

> She was *so* **much** *beautiful* ... (INCORRECT)

In this sentence **much** is an adverb. Generally **much** as an adverb can't modify a plain adjectives (that is the case here, and that's why this sentence is incorrect). Though it can modify a comparative or superlative adjective or a past participle of verb.

> He has not changed much. 
>   A much loved family member. 
>   The exam was much easier than I had expected. 
>   Loach’s latest film is much the best thing he’s done.

Consider the following sentence -

> Glad that you are doing *so* **much** *better*.

See in this sentence **much** is coming after *so*, but this sentence is not wrong. So your assumption that no intensifier can come after *so* is actually wrong. This sentence is correct because the adverb - **much** - there is used to modify the comparative form of *good* - **better**.